# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" upon Save

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, gdi+

I'm trying to "resave" an image and am getting the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+". I've done some searching around this error, however haven't found a solution yet! Most of the suggestions mention:

- Checking that the stream isn't in use or locked (i.e. File streams)
- Make sure the stream isn't disposed for the lifetime of the object (shouldn't be as you'll see below)
- Attempting to replicate the object within a Bitmap object, and using that to save (didn't work for me)

The code I'm using is listed below:

```
using (Stream @imageStream = ResourceManager.CreateFile(finalResourceId, imageFileName))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageFile.ResourceObject))
    {
        using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            imageWidth = img.Width;
            imageHeight = img.Height;
            img.Save(@imageStream, img.RawFormat);
        }
     }
 }
```

In the code above, `ResourceManager.CreateFile` returns the equivalent of a `MemoryStream`, therefore there shouldn't be any "resourcing issues".

I don't suppose anyone else has come across this issue and is able to share their solution? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just so you know, you can combine those using statements.

Comment: has the folder you are saving to got ASPNET_MACHINE and NETWORKSERVICE write permissions?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion regarding the using statements.
As for the permissions query - these shouldn't come into play as I'm not writing to the file system, but rather keeping everything in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Scozzard for prompting me to think of a workaround!

```
int imageWidth, imageHeight;
using (Stream imageStream = ResourceManager.CreateFile(finalResourceId, imageFileName))
{
    using (Image img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFile.ResourceObject)))
    {
        imageWidth = img.Width;
        imageHeight = img.Height;
    }
    imageStream.Write(imageFile.ResourceObject, 0, imageFile.ResourceObject.Length);
}
```

Because I'm working completely in memory I don't really need to use the image object to re-save it as it is in the same image format - I can just copy the byte buffer to the new stream.

Thanks for your comments nevertheless!